# Create filter buttons from user input

Tags: vue.js

I've been trying to make filter buttons based on the user creating "tags" to each cocktail recipe. The filter buttons show up, but nothing happens when you click on them. I already have a filter for cocktail favorites, and that works fine. Any help would be appreciated!

```html
    <div id="below-nav">
      <div id="filter-and-sort-area">
        <div><b>Filter by:</b></div>
        <div class="line-break"></div>
        <div id="filter-and-sort-button-wrapper">
          <div class="filter-radio-toolbar">
            <!-- Favorite Filter -->
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" v-model="favoriteFilter" value="All" checked>
              <label for="radio1">Show All</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" v-model="favoriteFilter" value="true">
              <label for="radio2">Favorites</label>
            <!-- Tag Filters -->
            <input type="radio" id="radio3" v-model="tag">
              <label v-for="(cocktail, index) in cocktails" :key="index" v-if="cocktail.tag !== null" for="radio3">
                {{ cocktail.tag }}
              </label>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
  import axios from "axios";

  export default {    
    data: function () {
      return {
        cocktails: [],
        search: "",
        activeFilterAndSortButton: "",
        favoriteFilter: "All",
        tagFilter: "All",
      };
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.cocktailsIndex();
      this.colorToggle("Favorites");
    },
    computed: {
      filteredCocktails() {
        return (
          this.cocktails
            // search filter
            .filter(cocktail => {
              return cocktail.ingredient?.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) || cocktail.cocktail_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
            })
            // favorite filter
            .filter(cocktail => {
              if (this.favoriteFilter === "" || this.favoriteFilter === "All") {
                return this.cocktails
              } else {
                return cocktail.favorite === true
              }
            })
            // tag filter
            .filter(cocktail => {
              if (this.tagFilter === "") {
                return this.cocktails
              } else {
                return cocktail.tag
              }
            })
        )
      },
```

[here's what the favorite and tag filters look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojVYf.png)

And here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-filters-from-user-input-9g95kg?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: First thing I noticed was there's `v-model="tag"` but no `tag` data variable.  and the `v-for` looks like it's on the wrong element.  you should have multiple inputs for each tag, not one input with multiple labels.  Can you maybe provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with codesandbox or other online sandbox?  You can replace API data with mock hard-coded data.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-filters-from-user-input-9g95kg?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the corrections I would make:

v-for loop should create 1 input and 1 label for each filter

```html
<!-- Tag Filters -->
<template v-for="cocktail in cocktails">
  <span :key="cocktail.id" v-if="cocktail.tag">
    <input
      type="radio"
      :id="`radioFilter${cocktail.id}`"
      :value="cocktail.tag"
      v-model="tagFilter"
    />
    <label :for="`radioFilter${cocktail.id}`">
      {{ cocktail.tag }}
    </label>
  </span>
</template>
```

It's not recommended to combine `v-for` and `v-if` on the same element.  I split them onto a template and span element respectively that wrap a single input and label.

Another mistake corrected here was the fact that each label needs a unique "for" attribute, meaning each input needs a unique "id" attribute.  This can be done by binding [template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to these attributes and using a unique value such as the `cocktail.id`.

`value` attribute was also missing on the radio inputs. I set it to `cocktail.tag`.

---

As far as the script code, the array filter for tags just needed a comparison between `cocktail.tag` and `this.tagFilter`.

```js
// tag filter
.filter((cocktail) => {
  if (this.tagFilter === "") {
    return cocktail;
  } else {
    return cocktail.tag === this.tagFilter;
  }
})
```

Any truthy value is acceptable to return from a filter callback function, so in the `if` statement you *can* `return this.cocktails` which is the same as `return true`, but personally I prefer to return the current element.

[Updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-filters-from-user-input-forked-pr3f47?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Thanks that solved it! I noticed that duplicate tag filters showed up so I added a computed property to hide those duplicates: [updated codesandbox:](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-filters-from-user-input-forked-pqlly8)

Comment: No problem.  If the answer resolves your question please consider marking the answer as correct and upvoting it.

Comment: Done. Thanks again